# how do i convert an unsigned char array into an unsigned long long?

Tags: c++, c, type-conversion

let's say that i have 8 unsigned char, that i want to convert to an unsigned long long.

for example, if all char are equals to 0xFF, the unsigned long long would be equal to 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

what's the most efficient way to do that with C or C++?

Comment: What if all chars are not equal to 0xFF?

Comment: You mean 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF?

Comment: Did you try *reinterpret_cast< unsigned long long * >( your_array );

Comment: Which language, C or C++?  The C language does not have `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: true, but it does still have type-casts: `*((unsigned long long *)your_array);`

Comment: In C you could use sscanf(str, "%llx", &your_var);

Comment: big or little endian

Comment: that's perfect george, thanks you

Comment: @bruceg: only if the array is a string character array, but if is is actual bytes then you can't use `sscanf()`.

Comment: yeah, but you easily turn the 8 unsigned chars into a string

Comment: @GeorgeHoupis hopefully not, as that would cause undefined behaviour (violation of strict aliasing rule)

Answer (score 6):

For example:

```
unsigned char buffer[8] = { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF };
unsigned long long target;
memcpy(&target, buffer, sizeof target);
```

Note that if not all the elements of `buffer` have the same value, the result will depend on byte ordering (little-endian vs. big-endian).

This also assumes that `unsigned long long` is exactly 8 bytes. That's very commonly true, but it's not guaranteed. (It's also not guaranteed that a byte is exactly 8 bits; it can be more. An `unsigned char` is by definition 1 byte.)

Comment: Using `<stdint.h>` or `<cstdint>` and `uint64_t` will always give 8 bytes.

Comment: @Jason: No, it will always give 64 bits, or `64 / CHAR_BIT` bytes. But if you assume `CHAR_BIT==8`, then yes, `uint64_t` is always 8 bytes (if it exists!).

Comment: Very true, `char` isn't necessarily defined as a byte, which means a `uint64_t` may not hold the entire string.  The size mismatch could be even worse with `unsigned long long`.

Comment: @Jason: No, a `char` is by definition one byte in C and C++. A byte is not necessarily an octet (8 bits); it can be bigger. `unsigned long long` is at least 64 bits, but can be bigger. On the other hand, systems with `CHAR_BIT > 8` are rare (mostly DSPs), and I've never seen `unsigned long long` with a size other than exactly 64 bits.

Comment: I know signedness isn't defined for `char`, I didn't think it was actually defined as a byte though.

Comment: @Jason: That's how the C and C++ standards define the word *byte*.

Comment: Thanks, I just found it (*5.2.4.2.1p2* The value of `UCHAR_MAX` shall equal `2^CHAR_BIT - 1`).

Answer (score 5):

Instead of memcpy, you can directly assign the bits

```
  unsigned char buffer[8] = { 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff };
  unsigned long long l = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    l = l | ((unsigned long long)buffer[i] << (8 * i));
  }
```

I believe this is immune to endianness.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about my initial silly answer, really should have read the question more carefully.  Hopefully this one is more helpful.  The way you convert depends on whether the endianness of the long long representation in the byte array matches that of the architecture you are working on.

C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

// Assuming ca is at least 8 bytes, the size of long long, interpret the
//    first 8 bytes as long long.
// differentEndian == true means the endianness of the machine is
//    different from the representation in ca.
long long getLongLong( unsigned char * ca, bool differentEndian )
{
   long long retVal;

   if (differentEndian)
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
       {
           unsigned char _tmpCh = ca[i];
           ca[i] = ca[7-i];
           ca[7-i] = _tmpCh;
       }
   }
   retVal = *reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long *>(ca);

   return retVal;
}

int main()
{
   unsigned char cArray[] = {0xff, 0x1, 0x70, 0x2, 0x61, 0x3, 0x52, 0x4};

   unsigned long long ll = getLongLong( cArray, false );
   cout << "Result for same endian: " << hex << ll << " or " << dec << ll << endl;

   ll = getLongLong( cArray, true );
   cout << "Result for different endian: " << hex << ll << " or " << dec << ll << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Assuming ca is at least 8 bytes, the size of long long, interpret the
//    first 8 bytes as long long.
// differentEndian != 0 means the endianness of the machine is
//    different from the representation in ca.
long long getLongLong( unsigned char * ca, int differentEndian )
{
   long long retVal;

   if (differentEndian)
   {
       int i;
       for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
       {
           unsigned char _tmpCh = ca[i];
           ca[i] = ca[7-i];
           ca[7-i] = _tmpCh;
       }
   }
   memcpy( &retVal, ca, sizeof(long long));

   return retVal;
}

int main()
{
   unsigned char cArray[] = {0xff, 0x1, 0x70, 0x2, 0x61, 0x3, 0x52, 0x4};

   unsigned long long ll = getLongLong( cArray, 0 );
   printf("Result for same endian: %llx or %llu\n", ll, ll);

   ll = getLongLong( cArray, 1 );
   printf("Result for different endian: %llx or %llu\n", ll, ll);

   return 0;
}
```

The output from both versions is:

```
Result for same endian: 4520361027001ff or 311315039429591551
Result for different endian: ff01700261035204 or 1837509111016818739
```